# Approach to read a text file

Tags: c#, wpf, text-files

I have a predefined `List<string> Wellnames = new List<string>(){"CAM1","CAM2","CAM3"};`

I have a text file, which is always in the same format as shown. How do I extract/read the highlighted numbers in the example? i,e. for CAM1 and similarly for CAM2 and CAM3.

here is the excerpt of the file:

```
1------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------913 
 ALLOC                  Allocation/bundle report                               10835.0000 Days  report step 228,  1 Sep 2015
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |        Streamline      |         |                                                                       |                                   |                       |           |           |
 |          Bundle        |         |                              Surface Rate                             |          Surface Volumes          |                       |           |           |
 |------------------------|  Flow   |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|   Total Reservoir     |   Pore    |PV weighted|
 |  Start     |  End      | Direct  |          Oil          |         Water         |          Gas          |   Oil     |   Water   |   Gas     |       Rate            |  Volume   |  Pressure |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                  |   SM3/D   | Fraction  |   SM3/D   | Fraction  |   SM3/D   | Fraction  |    SM3    |    SM3    |  SM3      |  RM3/D    | Fraction  |    RM3    |   Bar     |
 |                                  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | CAM1                   |         | 9.13e-001 |           | 3.14e+001 |           | 9.13e-001 |           | 7.55e+004 | 1.50e+005 | 7.55e+004 | 3.26e+001 | 1.06e+000 | 2.29e+005 | 6.21e+001 | 
 | CAM1        CAM138     | Outflow | 2.82e-001 | 3.09e-001 | 9.63e+000 | 3.07e-001 | 2.82e-001 | 3.09e-001 | 1.99e+004 | 3.88e+004 | 1.99e+004 | 1.00e+001 | 3.07e-001 | 5.96e+004 | 6.17e+001 | 
 | CAM1        CAM255     | Outflow | 3.34e-002 | 3.66e-002 | 3.00e+000 | 9.57e-002 | 3.34e-002 | 3.66e-002 | 1.86e+004 | 4.05e+004 | 1.86e+004 | 3.07e+000 | 9.40e-002 | 6.00e+004 | 6.30e+001 | 
 | CAM1        CAM177     | Outflow | 2.12e-001 | 2.32e-001 | 1.10e+001 | 3.50e-001 | 2.12e-001 | 2.32e-001 | 1.94e+004 | 3.66e+004 | 1.94e+004 | 1.13e+001 | 3.46e-001 | 5.68e+004 | 6.13e+001 | 
 | CAM1        CAM582     | Outflow | 3.17e-001 | 3.47e-001 | 5.72e+000 | 1.82e-001 | 3.17e-001 | 3.47e-001 | 7.77e+003 | 1.33e+004 | 7.77e+003 | 6.10e+000 | 1.87e-001 | 2.14e+004 | 6.13e+001 | 
 | CAM1        CAM354     | Outflow | 6.87e-002 | 7.53e-002 | 2.05e+000 | 6.53e-002 | 6.87e-002 | 7.53e-002 | 9.80e+003 | 2.04e+004 | 9.80e+003 | 2.14e+000 | 6.56e-002 | 3.07e+004 | 6.34e+001 | 
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something? regex looks likes it would be a decent solution.

Comment: Well, it seems that you expect we write a full program for you.

Comment: @Jacobr365 This is my time facing this kind of work. I am learning online about "how to read text files". Basic functions like File.Readlines etc. I am wondering how to approach this problem.

Comment: Here's a tip: Find the lines that start with one of your predefined names, then split the rest of the line based on the whitespace and pipe characters ("|").

Comment: @Steve No I don't sir. I am asking for what's the best approach/examples on how to read such text files.

Comment: You should have a closer look at Microsoft BizTalk Server, using a Flat File Schema you could easily parse and process thousands of those files ;)

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of the text file you are talking about? Does it actually have the vertical bars and dashes as in your picture? What's special about the highlighted numbers? Are you extracting only them and no others?

Comment: @DourHighArch Added. For example, I need to use those highlighted numbers in some other calculation. But I believe it can be general too. I may have to use other numbers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this Regex will get you what you need.

```
@"\|\s+CAM1\s+(\S+)\s+\|\s+\S+\s+\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|\s+\S+\s+\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|\s+\S+\s+\|\s+(\S+)"
```

just change `CAM1` for what you are looking for.

I put together an example for you [here](http://rextester.com/ASNE85886)

Comment: Thanks!!  I just learnt so many things from that code snippet! @maksymiuk

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you know how to read the file line-by-line. Once you have a particular data line in a string, you can use the Split() method on the '|' character.  You'll get back a zero-based array, with each element holding the data from one column.  Index into the array at index 0 and trim the value to check for your identifier CAM1, etc.  If it's the one you want, you can grab the other values from their indexes in the array.

Seems like the simplest approach given the rigid data format.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best approach for solving this, is to iterate the file line by line using a `StreamReader` and then parsing out the necessary information.

```
public dynamic Read(string file)
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file))
    {
        while ((var line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("| CAM", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
            {
                var columns = line.Split('|').Select(x => x.Trim());

                // Parse the values here, put them in a DTO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ehssan I am gonna use your snippet as reference in the program.